# C# crashes on save (doc.Save(PATH);)

Tags: c#, xml, save

This program crashes on debug and highlights the "doc.Save(PATH);" at the end of the code.
I am trying to save the variables `cookieScore`, `additionAddition`, and `additionMultiplier` into an XML file.

I am getting information about it from here "http://visualcsharptutorials.com/net-framework/writing-xml-file"

```
private XmlDocument doc;
string PATH = @"C:\sample.xml";
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(PATH))
    {
        XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
        XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is saved game data");
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("data");
        XmlElement data = doc.CreateElement("data");
        XmlAttribute addition = doc.CreateAttribute("addition");
        XmlElement additionNumber = doc.CreateElement("additionNumber");
        XmlElement multiplicationNumber = doc.CreateElement("multiplicationNumber");
        XmlElement cookieSave = doc.CreateElement("cookieSave");

        addition.Value = "addition";
        additionNumber.InnerText = additionAddition.ToString();
        multiplicationNumber.InnerText = additionMultiplier.ToString();
        cookieSave.InnerText = cookieScore.ToString();

        doc.AppendChild(declaration);
        doc.AppendChild(comment);
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        root.AppendChild(data);
        data.Attributes.Append(addition);
        data.AppendChild(cookieSave);
        data.AppendChild(additionNumber);
        data.AppendChild(multiplicationNumber);

        doc.Save(PATH);
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Comment: Post your stack trace so people can help you

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException @har07

Comment: @user3733200: Try what I suggested below. Given the exception type I'm now positive it's what you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're getting an access related exception because you're trying to write to the root of your C drive. Try writing to your desktop instead:

```
string PATH = @"C:\Users\[yourusername]\Desktop\sample.xml";
```

Another option would be to try to run your EXE as admin. If it works, then you know that's your problem.