# Adding a folder in special folders C#

Tags: c#, path, directory, special-folders

I want to save an XML file into this directory...
C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\game\data.xml

I can navigate here...  string PATH = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData;
But how do I create the game folder and save data.xml here?

Comment: The `System.IO` namespace should have everything you need.  What have you tried?

Comment: If you update the code in the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770229/c-sharp-crashes-on-save-doc-savepath) you recently asked to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` it will very likely just work.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Place this at the top of the file
using System.IO;
...
// Whatever you want to save.
var contents = "file contents";

// The app roaming path for your game directory.
var folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "game");

// Creates the directory if it doesn't exist.
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

// The name of the file you want to save your contents in.
var file = Path.Combine(folder, "data.xml");

// Write the contents to the file.
File.WriteAllText(file, contents);
```

Hope that helps.